# From .txt file to dictionary

Tags: python

i'm using python 2.7, and I need to do some algorithm and I need some help:
The function need to read some data: the data model is like this:

> # some_album   *song_name::writer::duration::song_lyrics

All over the txt file, I need to get into every position like : the album name and the song name using the function `split()`.
I have some questions:

1. how can I use split() between two characters- example: to an Album name, split between # to *   ????
2. I want to divide all the txt file to a dictionary, the albums is the key's and the value is another dictionary that his key's is the song name and the value is a list of all the lyrics in the song. mt question is how can i do it with a loop or any other idea, because i want it to divide the hull txt file, and not just part of him.
   this is what i do until now:

   ```
   data_file = open("<someplace>","r")
   data = data_file.readlines()
   data = str(data)
   i=0
   for i in data:
       albums= {data.split('#','*')[0] : data.split("::")[0]}
   ```

   to print just the album and the name of the first song. I dont understand how to do it with some loop??

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited the question to include a few example lines from your text file, and what output you are expecting to get.

Comment: You can just split at the `*` and then save the `[0]` element as the album name. perform another split on `::`, and save the `[0]` element as the name of first song.

The other alternative is to use regex.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your first question I would recommend to use the "Regular expressions operations module" `re` for this.

```
>>> import re
>>> str = 'py=th;on'
>>> lst = re.split("=|;",str)
>>> lst[1]
'th'
```